# C# mocking telerik ui class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test on ASP.Net project using Telerik UI components.

This is the unit test code which I am trying to test the method rbCreateTask_Click().

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            var dropdown = new Mock<RadDropDownList>();
            dropdown.SetupGet(rddlCategory => rddlCategory.SelectedText)
                 .Returns("select");

            var mockView = new Mock<Task>();
            mockView.SetupGet(x => x.rddlCategory).Returns(dropdown.Object);
        }
```

The issue is that this Task class is a web form with Telerik UI components.

This is the method that is called under test:

```
protected void rbCreateTask_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (rddlCategory.SelectedText.ToLower() == "select")
```

So here there is this `protected internal RadDropDownList rddlCategory` variable which I am trying to mock in the unit test but unable to do so, any suggestions will be welcomed!

The unit test error message is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'.
```

[**UPDATED**: inputs from Toumash]

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the entire class you are using. The one that has rbCreateTask_Click inside. Then you can provide the dropdown list mock.

That would be something like

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var dropdown= new Mock<RadDropDownList>();
    dropdown.SetupGet(x => x.SelectedText)
         .Returns("select");
    var mockView = new Mock<MyView>();
    mockView.SetupGet(x=>x.rddlCategory).Returns(dropdown);

    mockView.rbCreateTask_Click(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Toumash, thanks for the input! I have updated my question and there is one more invalid cast issue with the SetupGet as described.

Comment: @user990639 try to use `dropdown.Object` in `.Returns(dropdown.Object)`

Comment: yep i had use `mockView.SetupGet(x => x.rddlCategory).Returns(dropdown.Object)`;

Comment: What about the Page.Validate? It this the code that is the reason for the error? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Oh, use `Setup` without the `Get`part. Its used for properties, but the rddlCategory is a field, not a property https://forums.asp.net/t/1453669.aspx?Unable+to+cast+object+of+type+System+Reflection+RtFieldInfo+to+type+System+Reflection+PropertyInfo+